# How to specify a GKE node pool configuration in a YAML file instead of using gcloud container node-pools create?

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

It seems that the only way to create node pools on Google Kubernetes Engine is with the command `gcloud container node-pools create`. I would like to have all the configuration in a YAML file instead. What I tried is the following:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: NodeConfig
metadata:
  annotations:
    cloud.google.com/gke-nodepool: ares-pool
spec:
  diskSizeGb: 30
  diskType: pd-standard
  imageType: COS
  machineType: n1-standard-1
  metadata:
    disable-legacy-endpoints: 'true'
  oauthScopes:
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
  - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append
  serviceAccount: default
```

But `kubectl apply` fails with:

```
error: unable to recognize "ares-pool.yaml": no matches for kind "NodeConfig" in version "v1"
```

I am surprised that Google yields almost no relevant results for all my searches. The only documentation that I found was the one on Google Cloud, which is quite incomplete in my opinion.

Comment: Node pools are not Kubernetes objects, they are part of the Google Cloud API. Therefore Kubernetes does not know about them, and `kubectl apply` will not work. What you actually need is a solution called "infrastructure as code" - a code that will tell GCP what kind of node pool it wants. If you don't strictly need YAML, you can check out `Terraform` that handles this use case. See: https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_node_pool.html 

You should also look into `Google Deployment Manager` or `Ansible`, they also address your requirement.

Comment: @UtkuÖzdemir Thanks, that makes things much clearer. If you want to make that an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Node pools are not Kubernetes objects, they are part of the Google Cloud API. Therefore Kubernetes does not know about them, and kubectl apply will not work.

What you actually need is a solution called *"infrastructure as code"* - a code that will tell GCP what kind of node pool it wants.

If you don't strictly need YAML, you can check out Terraform that handles this use case. See: https://terraform.io/docs/providers/google/r/container_node_pool.html

You can also look into *Google Deployment Manager* or *Ansible* (it has GCP module, and uses YAML syntax), they also address your need.

Answer (score 0):

I don' know if it answers accurately your needs but if you want to do IAC in general with Kubernetes, you can use [Crossplane](https://crossplane.io/) CRDs. If you already have a running cluster, you just have to install their helm chart and you can provision a cluster this way:

```
apiVersion: container.gcp.crossplane.io/v1beta1
kind: GKECluster
metadata:
  name: gke-crossplane-cluster
spec:
  forProvider:
    initialClusterVersion: "1.19"
    network: "projects/development-labs/global/networks/opsnet"
    subnetwork: "projects/development-labs/regions/us-central1/subnetworks/opsnet"
    ipAllocationPolicy:
      useIpAliases: true
    defaultMaxPodsConstraint:
      maxPodsPerNode: 110
```

And then you can define an associated node pool as follows:

```
apiVersion: container.gcp.crossplane.io/v1alpha1
kind: NodePool
metadata:
  name: gke-crossplane-np
spec:
  forProvider:
    autoscaling:
      autoprovisioned: false
      enabled: true
      maxNodeCount: 2
      minNodeCount: 1  
    clusterRef:
      name: gke-crossplane-cluster
    config:
      diskSizeGb: 100
      # diskType: pd-ssd
      imageType: cos_containerd
      labels:
        test-label: crossplane-created
      machineType: n1-standard-4
      oauthScopes:
        - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only"
        - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write"
        - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring"
        - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol"
        - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly"
        - "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/trace.append"
    initialNodeCount: 2
    locations:
      - us-central1-a
    management:
      autoRepair: true
      autoUpgrade: true
```

If you want you can find a full example of a GKE provisionning with Crossplane [here](https://medium.com/dzerolabs/using-crossplane-to-provision-a-kubernetes-cluster-in-google-cloud-cf5374d765ee).